# Check if files exists

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I need to check if files mentioned in a text file exists or not and if they do not exist, then I need to place a dummy file at that location.

I used this which gives me the missing files, can somebody help me how to create these files?

```
Import-Csv .\Book3.csv | ForEach {
    If (Test-Path -Path $_.File) {
        Write-Output "$($_.File) exists"
    } Else {
        Write-Output "$($_.File) does NOT exist"
        $_.File | Out-File .\missingFiles.txt -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Take a look into `Test-Path` and `New-Item` and have a go at writing some code, if you get stuck ask again and include your code.

Comment: I've updated your question with your code

Comment: could you please un-delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638869/unsupported-config-option-for-services-volumes? I would like to know the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This will create a blank file when it does not exist

```
Import-Csv .\Book3.csv | ForEach {
    If (Test-Path -Path $_.File) {
        Write-Output "$($_.File) exists"
    } Else {
        Write-Output "$($_.File) does NOT exist"
        $_.File | Out-File .\missingFiles.txt -Append
        New-Item -Path $_.File -ItemType "file"
    }
}
```

Comment: @RanadipDutta ?

Comment: @SiddharthMishra Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).